# how to get the value of a variable in an active android service?

Tags: android, android-studio, service

In my app I have a service that handles the bluetooth connection and when a stage is completed a variable of type (int) changes.

For Example:

```
public static final int S_STATE_CONNECTED = 3;
public static final int S_STATE_CONENECTION_LOST = 4;
int State;

private final class CountHandler extends Handler{
CountHandler(Looper looper){
    super(looper);
}
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg){

    connect();  //Here int State Changes

}
```

connection process:

```
public void connect(){
    //some process
    State = S_STATE_CONNECTED;
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ACTION_BT_SERVICE_CONNECTED);
    resultIntent.putExtra("addressDevice",nameAddress);
    resultIntent.putExtra("nameDevice",nameDevice);
    localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(resultIntent);
}
```

In my service I send this data with a `LocarBroadcastManager`
and in my activity I handle them with a `BroadcastReceiver`and in function of what I recive I modify the UI.

I would like to obtain the value of `State` that indicates the different states of my connection so that when I start another activity I know the current state of my connection and show the corresponding information.

Answer (score 0):

In your connect method add this

```
public void connect(){
    //some process
    State = S_STATE_CONNECTED;
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ACTION_BT_SERVICE_CONNECTED);
    resultIntent.putExtra("addressDevice",nameAddress);
    resultIntent.putExtra("nameDevice",nameDevice);
    //send your state as extra 
    resultIntent.putExtra("currentState",State);
    localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(resultIntent);
}
```

In your UI activity,you can get that extra and update your ui accordingly.

Comment: And if I need to check it regularly?
I have to wait for the state to change? or I can implement a Handle Runnable that sends the status every x time